# How to extract links where I have put the specifications in Protege

Tags: protege

I have build a couple of ontologies in Protege. I want to find/extract the links where those specifications are stored in the web. I am trying googling, but either I ask it the wrong way, or such information does not exist.....Thanks

Comment: To ask it other way: I have an ontology that is an extension of another. The inintial ontology has an Ontology IRI and and an Ontology Version IRI. When I extended the initial ontology and saved on my PC as "OntologyExtended.owl", this action didn't change the initial  ontology file, stored on the position that Ontology IRI and Ontology Version IRI. How can I make the extended ontology to be stored on the initial ontology path, and get a changed .ttl file and obviously different IRIs?

Comment: I have found this: http://protege-project.136.n4.nabble.com/Change-Ontology-IRI-in-Protege-5-0-0-td4666378.html Ok, I believe I should not change the initial ontology's IRI, because other people using it. Second question, I have build a couple new ontologies from scratch. How do I save them with unique IRI for each one? Because for now, even though everything I have stored in .owl files, they are shown as "untitled-xxx" on their IRIs Thanks...

Comment: How do I save the IRI of a new ontology is the question...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify a file hosted on a web site (assuming the original ontology is stored as a plain file).

What is essential is that you have write access to the location. If so, all you have to do is write the new file in the correct location.

If the ontology is not just served as a plain file, you need to provide more details. The update will depend on how the original ontology is served.

The version IRI can be anything you wish; the ontology IRI can be (for example) a GitHub repository URL and a file name, and match an existing GitHub file, but that's not necessary. These are not used to decide where to ave the ontology. If you try to save an ontology loaded from an URL, the URL used to load the ontology will be the document URL, and will be used to try and save the changes, but it does not need to match the ontology IRI.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can I use github to store the ontologies from the Protege? I mean , what I need is when I open the ontology to  respond in an active link on my github account. Is this achievable, or the ontologies are saved on another "protege-type" webspace?

Comment: Many ontology repositories are using github to store and serve their files, not sure if anyone is saving directly to github. You could certainly save in a local repository and push your commits - I think that's fairly common.

Comment: On the field: "Ontology Version IRI" Ι put the link of github repository right?  What do I put on the field "Ontology IRI" ? Thanks for all your help..